# Special name for tuned car

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there some pejorative name for a street car that has been tuned, in most cases, for drift.

The main features - the engine swap and increased power, and at the same time a complete disregard for the body, which is mostly shabby and rusty.

Example image from [customculture.ru](https://customculture.ru/upload/resize_news/373a738b49c82ba10640abe2f59d3a65.jpg):

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should ask at [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: A souped-up clunker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although some controversy exists over the term's racist origins, ["ricer"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_burner) (or "rice rocket," as [The Photon](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/24129/the-photon) mentioned in the comments)  refers to a poorly- or over-tuned car. ["Tuner"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car_tuning) generically describes a modified car:

> The essence of modification of a tuner car is an attempt to extract the greatest possible performance—or the appearance of high performance—from the base motor vehicle through the addition, alteration or outright replacement of parts.

Along these same lines, a well-tuned car with an unassuming exterior can be called a ["sleeper."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeper_(car))

[This online forum](https://www.carthrottle.com/post/5668gvb/) (their expertise has no authority, but resources on this subject are limited) offers more specific definitions for "tuner" and "ricer" (edited  by me for grammar/syntax):

> A tuner is purposely built from the factory to be performance oriented. Note, FACTORY. Not your parking space, not your garage, not your dreams.
>
> Ricers are generally the exact opposite. Body kits, spoilers, wheels, sound systems, JDM parts (on some applications), and a bunch of other parts that make these cars obnoxious. A ricer's favorite mod is stickers. Typically defined as Hondas, but expanded to all sports cars that have zero performance value, imported or domestic.

Comment: It's probably worth including the alternative term, "rice rocket".

Comment: Although *ricer* / *rice rocket* doesn't really fit OP's request since they're typically very flashy rather than shabby or rusty.

Comment: Answer updated to include your suggestion! More synonyms are listed on the linked Wikipedia page, but I agree that your term is worth including since it might be more frequently used than "ricer" itself.

Comment: I'd disagree. Where I grew up, "ricer" matched the definition on [the Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_burner) (which is corroborated by a [cursory Google Images search](https://google.com/search?q=ricer&tbm=isch)): "overmodifying a sports compact, usually with oversized or ill-matched exterior appointments." I wouldn't use 'ill-matched' as a flashy term. Cars that *look* flashy but have garbage components might also be considered ricers, but flashy cars that are legitimately nice fall under "tuners" or "sleepers" by my definitions.

Comment: But OP specifically mentions that the body should be "shabby and rusty". A ricer typically uses a cheap base model car, but they don't let it get shabby or rusty. The term is pejorative because they're cheap and flashy, possibly with not-so-great performance; not because they're scruffy or rusty.

Comment: Fair enough. The slang for a rusty car is "rustbucket," but that doesn't confer being modified for drifting, which is simply "drift car." Making a car look shabby is called "ratting," so maybe OP would use "[ratted drift car](https://www.google.com/search?q=ratted%20drift%20car&tbm=isch)" or "[ratted tuner](https://www.google.com/search?q=ratted%20tuner&tbm=isch)."

Comment: The quoted paragraph is inaccurate in a number of respects.  Ricers are not generally sports cars, but small sedans.  In any case, Honda doesn't currently make a sports car.  The S2000 is probably too expensive for most of the ricer market (as it's in demand by those who want an actual sports car), and the long out of production del Sol is increasingly rare.  Also the favorite, and distinguishing, modification of a ricer is the obnoxiously loud "fart can" muffler.

Comment: This is not a sleeper, since sleeper try to look as stock car.
This is not rat-look, since bad exterior is not a goal, but a consequence of the fact that more dynamics are valued in the car and, often, the body crumples about obstacles during drift practice. It's not allways "shabby and rusty", but very often looks inaccurate and slightly damaged.